# Xcode 11 how to disable Auto Layout?

Tags: xcode, autolayout

In previous versions of Xcode, I was able to just open the storyboard and click almost anywhere, and in the file inspector, there was a button to disable auto layout. It seems like that's not an option anymore? Am I being forced to use auto layout now?

[image: screenshot of storyboard file inpsector with no autolayout option]

Answer (score 6):

According Apple [forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117300) this option silently disappeared in Xcode 11.

You can still do it programmatically at `viewDidLoad`

```swift
for constraint in self.view.constraints {  
    constraint.isActive = false  
}
```

Comment: This answer made all my UI controls cram into the upper left corner.

Comment: Are you using some other layout means?

Comment: Argh! I thought this would finally resolve my issue. I probably need to do something in the navigation controller, though. The issue is that I am using SideMenu to show several view controllers. I want one of them to not rotate when the device rotates. I tried this, but it didn't work. It must be the nav setting the frame that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Select your view in the storyboard and enable/disable LAYOUT automatic option in the right section

[image: xcode11]

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, highlight the constraint(s) on the left side and uncheck "Installed" in the Attributes Inspector